# Warning: Couldn't read data from file

Tags: http-put, openstack-glance, http-status-code-204

When i try to do an HTTP PUT request to upload a data file .img on image OpenStack like this:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token: $Token" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -d "@/home/nic/cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.img" 192.168.1.107:9292/v2/images/$ID_IMAGE/file
```

i receive this message:

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file 
Warning: "/home/nic/cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.img", this makes an empty POST.
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

I try to use absolute and relative path but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you check details of this file, using the user that you were running the curl command with? Eg please add the results of `ls -l /home/nic/cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.img`